# An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details. The error is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: vb.net, forms, object, instance

I get this error when attempting to debug my form, I cannot see where at all the error could be (also does not highlight where), anyone have any suggestions?

> An error occurred creating the form.
>   See Exception.InnerException for
>   details.  The error is: Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

```
Dim dateCrap As String = "Date:"
Dim IPcrap As String = "Ip:"
Dim pcCrap As String = "Computer:"
Dim programCrap As String = "Program:"

Dim textz As String
Dim sep() As String = {vbNewLine & vbNewLine}
Dim sections() As String = Text.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None)

Dim NewArray() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbNewLine)


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    textz = TextBox1.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: **When** does the error occur? Please remove all the irrelevant code from your question.

Comment: As soon as I debug, the whole point in this question was to see where the error was, so it could be anywhere - hence posting it all.

Comment: No … the error cannot be in any of the `Buttonx_Click` events, now can it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is here:

```
Dim textz As String = TextBox1.Text
```

and here:

```
Dim NewArray() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
```

and possibly here:

```
Dim sections() As String = Text.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

You cannot initialize a member like this because this code is basically executed in the constructor, **before** `TextBox1` (or any other control/property) is initialized, hence it is `Nothing`.

Put all initializations that refer to controls inside the `Form_Load` event – that’s what it’s there for.

Comment: Same outcome, can't seem to find anything else considering what you suggested.

Comment: @Ben: If the outcome is the same, then you’ve overlooked a similar initialization. Remove all other code form your form to reduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off "Just MY Code" under debugging section on the "Options>General" tab. That'll show you where the exact error originates.

Comment: I had a similar issue to OP, but mine didn't involve setting module level variables to form controls. Instead, mine related to having a checkbox on the form default to checked, which then fired the checkedchanged event, calling a subroutine which accessed a variable not yet initialized. Doing this helped to figure out the issue (I add `Sub Main` to my form, and wrapped a `Try...Catch` around the `InitializeComponent()` call).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptoms - couldn't even start debugging, as the error appeared before any of my code started to run. Eventually tracked it down to a resize event handler:

Private Sub frmMain_Resize(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize

```
ArrangeForm()
```

End Sub

As soon as I removed the handler, the error disappeared. The odd thing is that it had been running for about 3 weeks (while I developed other parts of the code) without any problem, and just spontaneously stopped working. A ResizeEnd event handler caused no problem.

Just posting this in case anyone else is unfortunate enough to encounter the same problem. It took me 8 hours to track it down.