# An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details. The error is: Stream is not a valid resource file

Tags: vb.net

I got this error after my computer shows a blue screen then restarted. Then I attempted to run my program but give me this error.
what should I do? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What code? Maybe this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866831/an-error-occurred-creating-the-form-see-exception-innerexception-for-details-t

Comment: Possibly the exe (or a dll) is corrupt. Have you run a chkdsk? Anyway: this is off topic (either belongs on [SU] with far more details – which application for a start, or needs code to show re-create if developing).

Comment: My program is already working. I just restart my computer. Thanks anyway. Godbless